# Sending hyper link as attachment in javamail using smtp

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am using javamail api to send email using smtp.

i have tried a typical example from [tutorial point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm).

But when i try to give a hyper link(https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-link_1.pdf) as attachment, i get the following error.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:\www.antennahouse.com\XSLsample\pdf\sample-link_1.pdf (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

is there a different method for hyper link as attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I downloaded the file using http request and the attached it.

Comment: Right, a URL is not a file.  You could've used URLDataSource to attach it directly.